# How pass variable in jquery easy confirm

Tags: jquery

By using javascript confim i have done suspending. Now i want to turn this to jquery easy confirm how can i do this

The function is called in a loop

My PHP Code:

```
function prepareRow( $flag, $Id )
{
$rowResponse = '<tr>    
                    <td style="width:12%"> ' . $Id . ' </td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="suspend" ></a> </td>
                </tr>'; 
return  $rowResponse            
}
```

Jquery easy confirm link: http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/

I have tried like this but if  click on 'yes' i want pass '$id' to it. So that i can suspend row.

Please help me out

```
$("#suspend").easyconfirm({locale: {
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'Are you sure, you want to suspend?',
    button: ['No',' Yes'],
    closeText: 'Close'
}});

$("#suspend").click(function() {
    $.post("suspend.php", { "Id" : Id }, 
            function(data){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "prepareTable.php",
                    success: function(data){
                    $("#example").html(data);
                }
                });
            });
});
```

Comment: "." (Dot) is use for Concatenate in PHP but in JavaScript Concatenate operator is "+"(plus sign). So you just need to change concatenate symbol :)

Comment: i am calling it in a php page. it is working my question is not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried example about jquery easy confirm in local system found bug in it. So i have stopped worry about this question and used jConfirm.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to look for callback's which will occur when you press Yes or No button. I would use http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/ You can see:
`'action': function(){}` Where you specify what to do after pressing yes or no