# Pass variable to click function jquery easy confirm

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How pass variable in jquery easy confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242437/how-pass-variable-in-jquery-easy-confirm)

Pass variable to click function jquery easy confirm

By using javascript confim i have done suspending. Now i want to turn this to jquery easy confirm how can i do this

My PHP Code ( this function is called in a loop ):

```
function prepareRow( $flag, $Id )
{
$rowResponse = '<tr>    
                    <td style="width:12%"> ' . $Id . ' </td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="suspend" ></a> </td>
                </tr>'; 
return  $rowResponse            
}
```

Jquery easy confirm link: http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/

I have tried like this but if  click on '**yes**' i want pass '**$id**' to it. So that i can suspend row.

Please help me out

```
$("#suspend").easyconfirm({locale: {
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'Are you sure, you want to suspend?',
    button: ['No',' Yes'],
    closeText: 'Close'
}});
$("#suspend").click(function() {
    $.post("suspend.php", { "Id" : Id }, 
            function(data){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "prepareTable.php",
                    success: function(data){
                    $("#example").html(data);
                }
                });
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried example about jquery easy confirm in local system found bug in it. So i have stopped worry about this question and used **jConfirm**.